# Can't embed in navigation controller if I am passing data with prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I am working on a custom camera app where I present 3 viewControllers modally. At each segue, I pass data with prepareForSegue function. My problem is after the work with camera is finished, I need to show 2 more viewControllers which need to be inside a navigationController.

I have realized that If I don't pass any data, the navigation controller works fine. However, when I pass data, the app crashes on runtime. What is the right way of doing this?

Here is my prepare for segue function;

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "camera2Crop"{
        let controller: CropViewController = segue.destinationViewController as CropViewController
        controller.photoTaken = self.photoTaken
    }
}
```

where `photoTaken`is an `UIImage` object. Moreover, here is the screenshot from my storyboard where I put the navigationController. I call the `prepareForSegue`function in `CustomCameraViewController` to segue to `CropViewController`.

[image: StoryBoard Screenshot]

**EDIT:** I have changed my prepareForSegue to the following code;

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "camera2Crop" {
        let controller: CustomNavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as CustomNavigationController
        controller.photoTaken = self.photoTaken

    }
}
```

Now the app does not crash but I don't know **how to send an object through Navigation Controller**

Comment: Can you share piece of your code where you share your data? I think you are trying to pass values to ui objects.

Comment: I have edited my post. Do you need anything else to understand where the problem is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
let controller: CropViewController = segue.destinationViewController as CropViewController
```

Double check if `segue.destinationViewController` is actually the navigation view controller.

If it's the navigation controller, get `CropViewController` from it:

```
if segue.identifier == "camera2Crop" {
    let navController = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
    let controller = navController.viewControllers[0] as CropViewController
    controller.photoTaken = self.photoTaken
}
```

Note you don't have to subclass UINavigationController.

Comment: It is not the navigation view controller. So that is the problem. I guess I should create a subclass of Navigation View Controller with a UIImage variable and pass the photoTaken object through navigation View controller. Is that correct?

Comment: very simple answer, glad I didn't have to subclass UINavigationController. Thank you.